# Getting value from ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get a value from ajax call, it shows in console-network-response log but I can't seem to get it into variable.

Here is script that send the data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Otevre modal
    $('.show-modal').click(function(){
        var productID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $("#itemBox").modal('show');
        // kod co otevre modal, mkrni na bootstrap manual jak je otevira nebo si otevreni nadefinuj sa
        $('.product_id').val(productID);
    });
    // Pridani do kosiku v modalu
    $('.add-to-basket').click(function(){
        var productID = $('.product_id').val();
        // skryty input do ktere si zapsal ID produktu po otevreni modalu
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: {id : productID},
            url: 'cart/cart.php?productID='+productID, // tomuto souboru predas idecko produktu, zapises do kosiku atd.
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Product was added to basket");
                // treba nejaka hlaska, ze byl pridan do kosiku
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and I am trying to echo it like so:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $product = $_REQUEST['id'];
    echo $product;
}
```

But it echoes nothing.

Comment: can you add `dataType:'text',` in the request

Comment: It is stored in the variable `data` in the `success` function and you are not doing anything with that yet.

Comment: y r u using query string if u r sending data ?

Comment: also chk `$_POST['productID']`

Comment: echoed nothing ?  where are you expecting to echo it. Checked your console ?

Comment: I want to use that value in my php code, i just wanted to echo it so i know its there, but after that i want to store it in an array

Answer (score 1):

Php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
  $product = $_REQUEST['id'];
  echo $product;
}
```

JS:

```
success: function(response) {
    // response will contain what ever $product echo's
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your code is working properly. **data** contains the **echo $product** value. You can get the value from **data** variable.

```
success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
```

Please let me know if you wanted to different thing.

Comment: I probably wanted something else, basically this script should give a ID value to modal window and then after pressing button "Add to cart" it should pass that ID to php file where i want to work with it.

Comment: Then you can store the ID in a hidden field when you get  it in the success function of ajax request. When **Add to cart**  button is clicked then fetch the ID from the hidden field and send to php file where you want to process.

Comment: So basically store it in <input> then get it with JS store it there in a variable and after that get it in my php code where I need it ? how do i get it from js to php ?

Comment: I think you call a ajax request when Add to cart button is clicked. Get the value from the hidden field with JS and pass it with the request like **data: {id : productID}**

Comment: isnt that what I am doing right now ? when i click Add to cart button, then i pass the value from hidden field to productID and then i pass it with request like you said... idk i am working on ecommerce website, but i never used JS before so i am trying to use as little as possible until i am done with other things.. But i manage to solve it by passing the argument like that document.cookie= 'id='+productID, and then getting it with $_COOKIE['id'] in my php file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code, and it seemed to work.  Try using this in javascript?

Try this.  I hope I helped

```
success: function(data) {
  alert(data.reponseText);
}
```